# получить HAR файл с помощью browsermob proxy

Tags: python, google-chrome, браузер, xhr

есть код

```
import time
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver

class ProxyManger:

    __BMP = "/home/admin/Documents/BrwMob/venv/bin/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy"

    def __init__(self):
        self.__server = Server(ProxyManger.__BMP)
        self.__client = None

    def start_server(self):
        self.__server.start()
        return self.__server

    def start_client(self):

        self.__client = self.__server.create_proxy(params={"trustAllServers": "true"})

        return self.__client

    @property
    def client(self):
        return self.__client
    @property
    def server(self):
        return self.__server
if "__main__" == __name__:
    proxy = ProxyManger()
    server = proxy.start_server()
    client = proxy.start_client()
    client.new_har("google.com")
    print(client.proxy)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server={}".format(client.proxy))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://google.com/")

    time.sleep(10)

    pprint.pprint(client.har)
    server.stop()
```

пытаюсь получить har файл с сайта, при запуске гугл пишет: "your connection is not private", добавил сертификаты в гугл для browsermob proxy https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/browsermob-core/src/main/resources/sslSupport/ca-certificate-rsa.cer, отключил в настройках безопасность, но ничего не помогло, что мне нужно сделать чтобы это заработало?

Answer (score 1):

Что мне помогло: options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')